# How to find a place to share with other expats or students in Leiden

Tags: netherlands, accommodation

I am an expat in Leiden searching for accommodation. I am willing to share with other expats or students (since Leiden is a student city). What I am looking for is a room in an apartment (or house) where the other rooms are occupied by other people (expats or students)

How can I find a place to share? Any websites for searching (registering)?

Answer (score 1):

Google search for sites and blogs targeted at expats and students. For example:

**[Life in Leiden: How to find a room](http://www.contrastleiden.nl/life-in-leiden-1-how-to-find-a-room/)**
We are glad you found your way to Leiden! The Life in Leiden blog is here to help you find your way around Leiden. This entry will be all about housing. We’d like to take you through the various options to find a room. We’ve listed some ways to go about this below.

**[Universiteit Leiden](http://www.studenthousing.leiden.edu/search-suggestions/leiden.html)**
If you are looking for a place to live in the private sector, you may find some useful suggestions on this page.

**[Erasmus Netherlands](https://erasmusu.com/en/erasmus-leiden/roommate)** roommate search